# How do I restore the sprite into original image after swapped it to another one in coco2dx?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

In my gaming context, the sprite is a smiling baby, when the baby is touched, the current sprite image changed to a crying baby, then after 3 seconds of crying sound effect ended, the sprite will restore to the smiling baby image.

My problem is

1. How to swap back with the previous image?

I have changed the smiling baby to a crying one, but i have no idea how could I swap it with the original smiling one?

2. How to ensure one click at one time?
   Each time the baby sprite is touched, the audio will start to play which is not ideal, because I hope the event function is only called after the previous event process is finished.

here is my code, and thank you a lot!

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    // 1. super init first
if ( !Layer::init() )
{
    return false;
}

Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
Vec2 origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();

//add background scene
auto backgroundSprite = Sprite :: create("scene001.jpg");
backgroundSprite->setAnchorPoint(Vec2(0,0));
backgroundSprite->setScaleX((visibleSize.width / backgroundSprite->getContentSize().width) * 1);
backgroundSprite->setScaleY((visibleSize.height / backgroundSprite->getContentSize().height) * 1);
addChild(backgroundSprite);

//add smileBaby sprite
auto smileBabySprite = Sprite :: create("figure001.png");

smileBabySprite -> setPosition(Vec2(500,400));
addChild(smileBabySprite);

//add crying audio
auto audio = CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance();

auto babyListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
babyListener -> onTouchBegan = [smileBabySprite, audio](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    //change smileBaby sprite to cryingBaby sprite
    smileBabySprite->setTexture(CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImage("figure002.png"));
    audio -> playEffect("babycry.mp3",false,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);

    return true;
};

babyListener -> onTouchEnded=[smileBabySprite](Touch* touch, Event* event )
{

};



_eventDispatcher -> addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(babyListener, this);

return true;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to keep *state* about if the baby is crying or not.  The best thing to do is keep this logic in a custom `Node` subclass.

Here is some (almost pseudo-)code to get you started:

Baby.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "cocos2d.h"

class Baby : public cocos2d::Node
{
private:
    cocos2d::Sprite *_sprite;    // Weak reference
    bool _crying;
    float _cryingTime;

public:
    CREATE_FUNC(Baby);

protected:
    virtual bool init() override;
    virtual void update(float delta) override;

public:
    void touched();
    bool isInside(cocos2d::Touch *touch) const
protected:
    void setSprite();
};
```

Baby.cpp:

```
#include "Baby.h"

USING_NS_CC;

bool Baby::init()
{
    if (!Node::init())
        return false;
    _crying = false;
    setSprite();
    scheduleUpdate();
    return true;
}

void Baby::update(float delta)
{
    Node::update(delta);
    if (_crying) {
        _cryingTime -= delta;
        if (_cryingTime <= 0.0f) {
            _crying = false;
            setSprite();
        }
    }
}

void Baby::touched()
{
    if (_crying)
        return;      // Already crying
    _crying = true;
    _cryingTime = 3.0f;    // Length of audio, I guess?
    setSprite();

    // Start crying sound here
}

bool Baby::isInside(Touch *touch) const
{
    Vec2 locationInNode = _sprite->convertToNodeSpace(touch->getLocation());
    Size size = _sprite->getContentSize();
    Rect rect = Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height);
    return rect.containsPoint(locationInNode);
}

void Baby::setSprite()
{
    if (_sprite)
        _sprite->removeFromParent();

    _sprite = Sprite::initWithFile(_crying ? "baby_crying.png" : "baby.png");
    Vec2 size = getContentSize();
    _sprite->setPosition(size.width * 0.5f, size.height * 0.5f);
    addChild(_sprite);
}
```

You add the `Baby` node in the parent instead of the sprite, using:

```
_baby = Baby::create();
_baby->setPosition(Wherever);
addChild(_baby);
```

Where `_baby` is an instance variable and use the `isInside()` method to test if a touch event is within the bounds of the sprite and call its `touched()` method:

```
Touch *touch = ...;
if (_baby->isInside(touch)) {
    _baby->touched();
}
```

and the `Baby` object will ignore the touch depending on state.

Comment: but there's a new problem @trojanfoe, if it inherits from node, then baby becomes a node, and unlike a sprite, it only allows click on the baby.png, you can click any where in the scene to trigger the function that makes the baby cry, what should we do to make it only clickable within the png image?

Comment: @Zoe I have added an `isInside()` method that can be used to test if a touch event is within the bounds of the baby node.  I have updated the explanation of how to use the node as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe really helpful you rock! thanks for your beautiful code!